# INSERT fails because primary key already exists

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, sequence, postgresql-9.4

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 and pgAdminIII 1.20 client. When launching an `INSERT` on a particular table, I get an error message saying: **`Details: the key (gid)=(31509) already exists. (SQL State: 23505)`**.

I do not enter a gid value in the command in order to let the sequence do the job:

```
INSERT INTO geo_section (idnum, insee, ident) VALUES (25, '015233', '') ;
```

The sequence is defined as this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE geo_section_gid_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 31509
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE geo_section_gid_seq
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The following query returns `34502`:

```
SELECT max(gid) FROM geo_section ;
```

Therefore, I've tried to alter the sequence in order to start sequence from `34503`:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE geo_section_gid_seq START 34503 ;
```

I get a success message saying that the query has been executed properly. But the sequence `START` parameter remains with `31509` value...

Comment: Maybe you forgot (after creating the sequence) to attach it to geo_section.gid ? `ALTER TABLE ONLY  geo_section ALTER COLUMN gid SET DEFAULT nextval('geo_section_gid_seq'::regclass);  ALTER SEQUENCE geo_section_gid_seq OWNED BY geo_section.gid;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the next value for sequence use setval function :

```
     select setval('geo_section_gid_seq'::regclass,34503,false)
```

false : if you want the next value will be 34503

true : if you want the next value will be 34504

Answer (score 0):

You should execute this command:

```
SELECT setval('geo_section_gid_seq', (SELECT MAX(gid) FROM 'geo_section'), true)
```